# Fresh install of ubuntu 22.04 LTS on virtual machine doesn't recognise my RTX 4090

Tags: nvidia, vmware-player

I am attempting to install nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a vmware virtual machine. I have downloaded the latest drivers (525.89.02) and run the .run script. I get the following error[image]

Is this error message correct? Are 4090s simply not supported on linux? Is there some mesa-based alternative? This is what the additional drivers tab in Software & Updates currently says

[image]

It looks like these drivers are the appropriate drivers too

[image]

PS Running glxinfo -B gives me this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Machines do NOT have access to the "host" hardware.

VMware provides a much better driver for the VM to use. And that is what your using.

The message saying "not an nVidia chip" is exactly right.  VMware will be reporting some generic hardware graphics chipset - you have some control over this in the VM ware machine settings.

But the nVidia driver is only needed by the Host operating system, the machine you start VMware player in.